# Invalid Token When Using Alamofire

Tags: oauth-2.0, alamofire

Environment: Swift 2, iOS 9

I had rolled my own HTTP networking library. It wasn't broken but I decided to fix it and switch to Alamofire.

Here is my code snippet:

```
  case .HTTPTokenAuth:  // Token Auth

  let dictionary = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("Auth_Token", inService: "KeyChainService")
  let token = dictionary!.valueForKey("access_token")

  var aManager = Manager.sharedInstance
  aManager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token!)" ]
  aManager.request(method, requestURL!, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).response { request, response, data, error in

    print("===== Request ================")
    print(request!.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
    print("===== Response ================")
    print(response!.allHeaderFields)
    print("===== Error ================")
    print(error)

  }
```

The problem is that for some reason the Oauth token is not making it into the header. (At least that is what appears to be the problem as I don't see it in the Request header. I receive the following request/response:

```
===== Request ================
["Content-Type": "application/json"]

===== Response ================
[Content-Type: application/json, 
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Doorkeeper", 
error="invalid_token", 
error_description="The access token is invalid", 
Pragma: no-cache, X-Runtime: 0.002205, 
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.14, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Server: nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.14, 
Transfer-Encoding: Identity, 
Cache-Control: no-store, 
Date: Tue, 01 Sep 2015 18:54:16 GMT, 
X-Request-Id: 395d2154-5054-423c-a7bc-f7ef85e0cdbf, 
Connection: keep-alive, 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, 
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1, 
Status: 401 Unauthorized, 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN]
```

Comment: Don't put `Authorization` in the session configuration `HTTPAdditionalHeaders` property. Set it on the individual requests instead.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the comment in the docs about putting header information that doesn't change into the session configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the simpler approach:

```
case .HTTPTokenAuth:  // Token Auth

  let dictionary = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("Auth_Token", inService: "KeyChainService")
  let token = dictionary!.valueForKey("access_token")
  let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token!)"]

  Alamofire.request(method, requestURL!, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
           .response { request, response, data, error in

    print(request!.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
    print(response)
    print(error)

  }
```